# Are the words "other" and "further" interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice

For example is it better to say:

> 1. We work with this company in Germany and with other companies in Europe
> 2. We work with this company in Germany and with further companies in Europe

Comment: Further doesn't make any sense here.  The first sentence is okay.

Answer (score 1):

"Further" doesn't make any sense there. "Further" means that whatever is either before or after it in the sentence (both are fine) is true to a greater extend. Example: We need to further improve the quality of our stock. (=to improve it even more). You will also see it in the following form: Further to our recent conversation, we are writing to confirm details of the forecoming conference. In this case it is used to refer to an earlier action. Other is used to mention something apart from what has already been mentioned or something that differs from it.